# How to add asyn annotation on subclass methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Interface:

```java
interface IProcessor {
    void process(IRequest request);
}
```

Class:

```java
@Component
public class MyProcessor implements IProcessor {

    @Async("asyncConfigBean")
    @Override
    public void process(Irequest request){
        // Some logic..
    }
}
```

I am trying to make the method in subclass as async **but I am facing following exception:**

```
The bean 'myProcessor' could not be injected as 'com.demo.MyProcessor' becasue it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements: com.demo.ci.IProcessor
    
Action:
Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync
```

How do I resolve this issue? What will be implications of making `proxyTargetClass=true` in this situation? Is there any other way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the above description, the bean failed MyProcessor injection (reason for the failure is to implement an interface, and Spring Boot affairs default is to use JDK Dynamic Proxy, which is based on the interface).

> How do I resolve this issue?

Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of **CGLib-based proxies by setting `proxyTargetClass=true` on `@EnableAsync`**.

###### Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces:

```java
@RestController
public class ProcessorController {

    private final IProcessor iProcessor;

    public ProcessorController(IProcessor iProcessor) {
        this.iProcessor = iProcessor;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/processor")
    public String processor() {
        iProcessor.process(null);
        return "processor";
    }
}
```

###### Forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class AsyncConfiguration {}
```

> What will be implications of making `proxyTargetClass=true` in this situation? Is there any other way to resolve this issue?

If you want to force the use of CGLIB proxying (for example, to proxy every method defined for the target object, not just those implemented by its interfaces) you can do so. However, there are some issues to consider:

If you want to force the use of CGLIB proxying (for example, to proxy every method defined for the target object, not only those implemented by its interfaces), you can do so. However, you should consider the following issues:

- With CGLIB, final methods cannot be advised, as they cannot be
  overridden in runtime-generated subclasses.
- As of Spring 4.0, the constructor of your proxied object is NOT
  called twice anymore, since the CGLIB proxy instance is created
  through Objenesis. Only if your JVM does not allow for constructor
  bypassing, you might see double invocations and corresponding debug
  log entries from Spring’s AOP support.
- [Learn more about Proxying Mechanisms.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-proxying)